# Unpredicted voltage drop at the output of a Graetz bridge

Tags: voltage, diodes, bridge

I used a Graetz bridge to rectify the voltage after transforming but it ended up making an unusual voltage drop. I don't understand what is happening.

[image]

Comment: Connect a 1 μF capacitor in parallel to the output.

Answer (score 0):

The simulator's DC voltmeter doesn't appear to handle unsmoothed DC properly.

Try adding a 1 μF capacitor after the rectifier.

Comment: Thanks but I don't get what is going on with the circuit. The 1 μF capacitor raised the voltage to about 40 V so I guess having the right capacity can help me have the right output. But still this shouldn't be happening in the first place.

Comment: The unsmoothed DC is a full-wave rectified sinewave and so is changing all the time. It's not quite DC (in that it's not steady). The simulation meter just can't handle it.

Comment: If your simulator is capable of displaying the wave form across the DC voltmeter you would very clearly see the difference before and after the addition of the capacitor.